# sqlite3_bind_text() not binding placeholders

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to use placeholder parameters as described in the [sqlite documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).
Below is the code I'm running.

No matter how I position the `?` in the sql command, `sqlite3_bind_text()` doesn't work. I have also tried `@table`, `:table`, and `?1` as
placeholders. I even tried replacing the first two `exec` the calls with explicit `prepare`
and `step` calls.

What's interesting is that `sqlite3_bind_int()` works if I have a clause like:

```c
sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE rowid = ?;";
```

Using `sprintf()` also works:

```c
sprintf(sql, "SELECT %s FROM test;", "message");
```

---

```c
/* gcc -l sqlite3 retrieve.c -o retrieve */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main()
{    
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    int result;

    const char *sql;
    char *err_msg;
    
    err_msg = 0;

    result = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

    if (result)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return(1);
    }
                
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ("
        "id             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        "message        TEXT    NOT NULL );";

    result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    
    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL exec error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
    }

    sql = "INSERT INTO test (message) VALUES ('hi how ya doin');"; 
    
    result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &err_msg);
    
    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL exec error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
    }
                
    sql = "SELECT message FROM ?;"; /* doesn't work */
    /* sql = "SELECT ? FROM test;";    /\* doesn't work *\/ */

    result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    
    result = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "test", -1, SQLITE_STATIC); /* doesn't work */
    /* result = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "message", -1, SQLITE_STATIC); /\* doesn't work *\/ */
    
    if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind string\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("SQLITE_OK\n");
    }
        
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) /* checking for done leaves room for error */
    {
        printf("%s\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);    
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't bind table or column names, only values.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for that. Where is this documented? Put this and the source in an answer and I'll mark it.